# insert a data to particular cell in a wpf datagrid in c#

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

Hi i am new to wpf datagrid. i don't know how to insert the data in particular cell in a row of the wpf datagrid.

In normal windows form application i can achieve this by
binding the list with datagridview

```
dataGridView.Columns["UserName"].datapropertyName = "USERNAME";
dataGridView.Columns["Role"].datapropertyName = "Role";

 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = UserList;
 dataGridView.DataSource = bs;

for(int i=0; i<UserList.Count; i++)
{
   dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Company"].Value = "Default";
}
```

now i want to achieve the same in wpf datagrid can any one provide the sample code. sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a class containing the various Properties you want to be displayed.
I assume, since you already have a UserList, that the class is User (and implements INotifyPropertyChanged), and that the UserList is the list containing all the data.

First, if you want to add new users to UserList, and make the DataGrid update, the UserList variable needs to be of type ObservableCollection.

Then, in XAML, you bind the UserList up to the DataGrid. There is lot's of information on how to do this, but the simplest way is to set the DataContext to the class containing the UserList, and then just have the DataGrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding UserList}"/>
```

Then, to change the values, just edit the property of the user, not the grid.

```
for(int i=0; i< UserList.Count; i++)
{
   UserList[i].Company = "Default";
}
```